First fundamental form and shortest curve through two points.
I have been recently studying First Fundamental Forms and its relationship with the angle between two curves contained in a surface and the area of a region in the surface. But then I wondered if there is any link between the FFF of a surface $S$, $ds^2 = Edu^2 + 2Fdudv + Gdv^2$, given a parametrization of $S, \alpha(u,v), \alpha: \Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow S$.

For example, in the plane, with FFF $ds^2=da^2+db^2$, the shortest curve between two points is a straight line. In a sphere is a great circle and so on. Has this anything to do with the FFF? I think that that shortest curve is called geodesic, and that there are some equations related to how to calculate it, but I would like to know if there is any connection via FFF and even any way to calculate what it was mentioned above.

Maybe you should read a differential geometry text or two?

And maybe you should find a more productive way to release you anger issues? Find a psychologist maybe? It's not my problem if you're not getting laid you know
